# How to load a large .rda file selectively?

Tags: r, load, rstudio, rda

I have a large datafile in .rda and I can use load() into R studio.
It takes 3 minutes. I would like to speed it up. Is there anyway to speed up the loading?
Say somehow selectively.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You either load all or none of an `.rda` file. If it's multiple objects, consider splitting them into individual `.rda` files. If it's a large `data.frame`, you might consider the `feather` package for storing it, as it supports lazy reading. If it's anything else, there's little probability of helping you since we know nothing else.

Comment: Thank you! What I have is a .rda file. When I load it, it takes 2.65 minutes. But I need only 1/3 of it. So if there is a way to read only that part of what I need, I may save time in the loading. I guess no other way out.

Comment: There is no way to do a partial load, unfortunately.